# How to return boolean statement if the sum of an arraylist is less than or equal to a maximum number?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have the method head

```
public boolean legal(int total)
```

that must return `true` if the sum of the `ArrayList<Integer> numbers` is not higher than the parameter `total`.

Please help me on how I could implement this. Which type of loop is preferred?

Thanks.

Comment: Re, "Which type of loop...?" The time you spend worrying about the answer to that question is _wasted_ time. Your first step, in such a simple case, should be to write something—anything—that works. _Then_, if you have time, and if it's _worth_ the time, you can ask, "How could I do this _better?_" Save the pre-planning worries for when you're faced with a problem that's going to take days or weeks to solve. This problem should take only a few minutes to solve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to loop thotugh your list is by using a [foreach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/) loop

```
public boolean legal(int total) {

    int sum = 0;
    for(int num : numbers) { //loop through every number in ArrayList numbers
        sum += num;  
    }

    return sum <= total; //return true if the sum is less than or equal to total
}
```

A foreach loop is easier to use than a for loop since you do not to handle indeces. However a foreach loop can only be used if your collection have indices, which for your case an ArrayList have. Therefore a foreach loop is the easiest way to loop thorugh your list.

If your collection do not have indices (if your use for example a `Set`) you can instead use a regular [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) or an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: Better you call it [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Note: I haven't downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8** [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public boolean legal(int total) {
    return numbers.stream()
     .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // converts the stream to an IntStream object
     .sum() <= total; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to implement like this

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

public boolean legal(int total){
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
       sum += arr[i];
       i=i+1;
    } 
    if(sum <= total){
       return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: You can replace those last six lines with `return (sum <= total);`

Comment: Absolutely right, but he is labeled as new contributor so require more plain code to understand. I think so.